# Remove until end of the line after the same character from different locations in multiple lines

Tags: vim

I want to remove anything from `:` to the end of line in all of the following lines in Vim:

```
key1: A
key2_long: B
key3_longerrr: C
key: D
```

So the result would be:

```
key1
key2_long
key3_longerrr
key
```

For a single line I use `f:d$`. What are better ways to do this for all lines, wihtout repeating `f:d$` for all lines?

Answer (score 2):

`:%s/:.*//g`

It searches and replaces what matches the regex between the first and second / with what is between the second and third in all the file.

you can find more on this in the documentation, look for substitute

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with `f:d$` (which should be `f:D`), you can use `:normal` for a one-off macro:

```
:,+3normal f:D
```

or:

```
vjjj:normal f:D
```

See `:help :range` and `:help :normal`.